# Confusion in Logical AND operation

Tags: linux, operators, cc

I have some  confusion in how following expression works.

```
cc file_name.c  && ./a.out
```

When filename.c gets compiled successfully , its exist status would be 0 (zero). 
So as per logical && operation , second expression  ( ./a.out ) not suppose to be executed. 
But  it  still works and gives me result. How it works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` means success in the shell. It's not the same as in C.  From the [`bash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the **&&** and **││** control operators, respectively. AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity. An AND list has the form
>
> *command1* **&&** *command2*
>
> *command2* is executed if, and only if, *command1* returns an exit status of zero.

Answer (score 1):

When executing shell commands, a return value of 0 means the command was executed successfully. Non-zero value means there was an error processing the command. So, if previous command was a success it would proceed to the next command, else abort.